# Python 2.7 Unrecognized Character G in format string during runtime

Tags: string, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I have Python 2.7 Win 32 and have installed Matplotlib, Numpy, PyParsing, Dateutil. In IDLE I place in the code:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import numpy as np

def graphRawFX () :
    date=mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    bid,ask = np.loadtxt,unpack=True,('GPBUSD1d.txt')
    delimiter=',',
    converters={0:mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S') }
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,7))
    ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((40,40), (0,0), rowspan=40, colspan=40)

    ax1.plot(date,bid)
    ax1.plot(date,ask)

ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

I then proceed to enter:

```
rawGraphFX()
```

This results into the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    graphRawFX()
  File "C:/Users/Emanuel/Desktop/graph", line 16, in graphRawFX
    ax1.plot(date,ask)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 4137, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 317, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 276, in _plot_args
    linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 129, in _process_plot_format
    'Unrecognized character %c in format string' % c)
ValueError: Unrecognized character G in format string
>>>
```

This is probably easy to fix but I need help since I'm getting frustrated over this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two issues with these two lines:

```
date=mdates.strpdate2num('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
bid,ask = np.loadtxt,unpack=True,('GPBUSD1d.txt')
```

The first of these lines sets `date` to a class instance that would convert strings to matplotlib style dates.  However, you never supply the dates.  You need to come up with date strings from somewhere and apply this function to them.

The second line of these lines makes two assignments.  It first assigns `np.loadtxt` to True and `unpack` to `'GPBUSD1d.txt'`.  It consequently assigns `bid` to True and `ask` to `'GPBUSD1d.txt'`.  It is the latter that causes the `Unrecognized character` error when matplotlib tries to interpret the `G` in `'GPBUSD1d.txt'` as some kind of format instruction.  You probably intended something like:

```
bid, ask = np.loadtxt('GPBUSD1d.txt', unpack=True)
```

This would call the function `np.loadtxt` which would load the file `GPBUSD1d.txt'` and transpose ("unpack") it.

Comment: Could you tell me what a date string is? And what does it's function serve?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to plot prices against dates.  The purpose of the function is to convert the dates from the input format you have (you specified '%Y%m%d%H%M%S'` as the input format) to a format that matplotlib understands.  Where are the dates coming from?

Comment: The file called GBPUSD1d.txt. It states the year,date,month,hours,minute and second.

Comment: @BenthePyro Does GBPUSD1d.txt also contain the bid,ask data?  Can you show a several sample lines from the file?

Comment: I have already solved the string problem above. I now have a new problem: ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 20130501000000,1.55358,1.55371 The numbers are sample lines. If you need more just tell me.

Comment: @BenthePyro Your data is comma-separated.  `np.loadtxt` won't guess that; you have to tell it that explicitly.  Also, you want the first column as a string so you can feed it to `date`.  So:  `datestr,bid,ask = np.loadtxt('GPBUSD1d.txt', delimiter=',', dtype=np.dtype(np.str, np.float, np.float), unpack=True)`.  [See the docs for `np.loadtxt` for more details.](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html)